# How to check dependencies of a package under OpenBSD?

Tags: package-management, openbsd

AFAIK this is the way that I can install for ex.: XYZ on OpenBSD:

```
pkg_add -Uvi XYZ
```

How can I get a list for all the dependencies regarding XYZ package?

-> So I need a list about .tgz filenames that pkg_add will download/install/update when I need to install given XYZ package.

What is the command to generate a list for XYZ package?

Comment: please ask if it's unclear :)

Comment: Why not just grab the ports tree, and check the Makefile for the ports you care about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like dependencies are specified in the packing list.  You can see the packing list with `pkg_info -f`.

So, assuming `PKG_PATH` is already set:

```
pkg_info -f XYZ | grep '^@depend' | cut -f 3 -d :
```

should give you the package names.

Prepending `$PKG_PATH` and appending `.tgz` to each line should give you a URL that's probably what would be downloaded, e.g. to get `bash`'s dependencies:

```
PKG_PATH=http://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.1/packages/amd64/
export PKG_PATH
pkg_info -f bash | grep '@depend' | cut -f 3 -d : | while read package; do
    echo $PKG_PATH$package.tgz
done
```

prints

```
http://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.1/packages/amd64/libiconv-1.14.tgz
http://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.1/packages/amd64/gettext-0.18.1p1.tgz
```

See also `pkg_add -n` and `PKG_CACHE`.

References:

- [pkg_info(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pkg_info&sektion=1)
- [pkg_add(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pkg_add&sektion=1)

Comment: sqlports is simpler :) http://openports.se/databases/sqlports